# How to Inject Logged User into Property by Annotation

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I have an entity called Item as above:

```
<?php

/**
 * Item
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item {

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @var \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
     * ???
     */
    private $user;

    .....
```

How can I inject logged User object into $user property via annotation in the easiest way?

Comment: you want to 'inject' the currently logged in user into your Item entity ? that sounds pretty strange ... i guess you are looking for a way to store the user who actually created the Item entity right ? are you trying to log who has created / updated the item entity ?

Comment: @nifr Yes you are right!

Comment: sufficient answer? both provide exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save the created/updated timestamps and the user who performed these actions with your entity ... this is called blameable and timestampable behavior!

Have a look at [Knp\DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) including [blameable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#blameable) and [timestampable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#timestampable) behaviors. (PHP 5.4+ needed)

[Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) also provides blameable and timestampable. (PHP >=5.3.2)